# Would ping loss problems affect Ubuntu installation?

Tags: networking, system-installation, internet, wget

I have a 6 mbps internet connection. I've recently been experiencing ping loss, from 8% to 20%, with my ISP. I can still browse the internet and download files using `wget`; the download gets stuck at times but automatically resumes fine without a problem.

Now, I would like to delete Ubuntu 16.04.1 and install 17.04 (not upgrade). I already have the DVD image of 17.04.

My question is,

As Ubuntu uses network connection at installation time, would the ping loss problem affect installation? Would the installation be corrupted due to the network problem?

From what I understand, Ubuntu’s default download utility tool is `wget`, right? So as long it is using `wget` to download all the required files, the installation should be fine. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't believe it would affect it. But if it appears to, you can always opt not to download updates during installation and run them afterwards instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much every client-to-server file transfer protocol out there, including those involved in the upgrade process of Ubuntu, uses [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) connections underneath. TCP connections provide *reliable* links, meaning that they don't fail due to package loss as long as there will always be at least one successfully transmitted packaged at some point in the future (and before the connection times out).

This means that anything over 50 % package loss will slow down the transfer speed, possibly severely, but not make data transfer impossible.

Comment: I deleted my comments because the discussed issues were resolved or integrated into my answer which rendered the comments obsolete. You should delete yours too.

Comment: You already accepted my answer which should be enough confirmation of its usefulness. :-)